# can't install release app when it installed debug app on a device

Tags: android, debugging, apk, release

I made a very bad mistake.
I distributed a debug app for customers.
I want to distributing release app for customers.
if debug app installed then can't install release app.(App Not Installed error)

how to install release app when it installed debug app in device without uninstall debug app manually?
how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: You can try changing the app `package name`.

Comment: reply Hed Shafran : when changing package name twice of app installing in device be it is very bad

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty sure changing the package name is your only option here..

Comment: If your number of install are less than you can unpublish that app and the republish the new app with a different package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to update, because the app is signed with a different certificate and this is not allowed for security reasons.

The best solution is to uninstall and reinstall the app, but if that's not doable, you could continue signing the release app with the debug keystore. You can find it in `~/.android/debug.keystore`, with the default password `android`.